# A positive semidefinite matrix with negative eigenvalues

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

From what I know, for any square real matrix `A`, a matrix generated with the following should be a positive semidefinite (PSD) matrix:

```
Q = A @ A.T
```

I have this matrix A, which is sparse and not symmetric. However, regardless of the properties of `A`, I think the matrix `Q` should be PSD.

However, upon using `np.linalg.eigvals`, I get the following:

```
np.sort(np.linalg.eigvals(Q))
>>>array([-1.54781185e+01+0.j, -7.27494242e-04+0.j,  2.09363431e-04+0.j, ...,
        3.55351888e+15+0.j,  5.82221014e+17+0.j,  1.78954577e+18+0.j])
```

I think the complex eigenvalues result from the numerical instability of the operation. Using `scipy.linalg.eigh`, which takes advantage of the fact that the matrix is symmetric, gives,

```
np.sort(eigh(Q, eigvals_only=True))
>>>array([-3.10854357e+01, -6.60108485e+00, -7.34059692e-01, ...,
        3.55351888e+15,  5.82221014e+17,  1.78954577e+18])
```

which again, contains negative eigenvalues.

My goal is to perform Cholesky decomposition on the matrix Q, however, I keep getting this error message saying that the matrix Q is not positive definite, which can be again confirmed with the negative eigenvalues shown above.

Does anyone know why the matrix is not PSD? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that's a numerical problem, but I would say that `Q` is probably still PSD.

Notice that the largest eigenvalue is `1.7e18` while the smallest is `3.1e1` so the ratio is about, if you take probably `min(L) + max(L) == max(L)` will return true, meaning that the minimum value is negligible compared to the maximum.

What I would suggest to you is to compute Cholesky on a slightly shifted version of the matrix.

e.g.

```
d = np.linalg.norm(Q) * np.finfo(Q.dtype).eps;
I = np.eye(len(Q));
np.linalg.cholesky(Q + d * I);
```